# Any performance issues with passing in a db connection object each time I instantiate a class?

Tags: php, object, reference, scope

Many of my classes require access to a database to do their work. For a while I've been doing something like the following:

```
// Create a (one) database object
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "db");

// Pass database object into each new object that requires database interaction as follows
$car = new Car($data, $mysqli);
$plane = new Plane($data, $mysqli);
// etc
```

Then each class has a private $mysqli member which the passed in mysqli object is assigned to in the construct as follows:

```
class Car {

    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct($data, $mysqli) {

        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;

    }

}
```

Then class methods can use the mysqli object easily like this:

```
public function fuelLevel() {

    $this->mysqli->query("SELECT fuel_level FROM fuel_tank");

}
```

My question is, will I run into any performance issues if I were to create a few thousand of these objects? Am I correct in thinking that there is only technically one database connection in my entire application by doing so? Or should I be using references (pointers?) like below to avoid the feared performance overheads?

```
$car = new Car($data, &$mysqli);
$plane = new Plane($data, &$mysqli);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this cannot possibly cause any measurable performance impact. You are correct, there is a single connection object which you're passing by reference. This level of optimization isn't something you should be concerned with while developing in PHP.

You should absolutely not use call-time pass-by-reference (`new Car($data, &$mysqli)`), which is deprecated in PHP 5.3.

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused from other languages, I thought in languages (like C#, for example) when you pass variables into classes or functions, a copy of said variables is created (using a small amount of memory). Where would I user references/pointers as per my last snippet, since the mysqli object's state will never change? I'm probably just getting confused, sorry if that makes little sense.

Comment: Not true for PHP. When you pass an object into a function, you are always passing it by reference. That said, that "small amount of memory" is just that: a small amount of memory. This isn't something you should spend any time thinking about while developing in PHP, an interpreted language. Server-side performance is the very very last thing you should worry about while developing a website.

Comment: Thanks meagar, appreciate your help. Will mark as correct in 7 minutes when I'm allowed.